# Vora support for ORC files - char() type?

Tags: orc, vora

Is there any reason why Vora's ORC reader doesn't support char() type? Here's what I got when trying to read a file of a Hive ORC-based table containing char(n) fields:

```
com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClientException: Could not load table FLIGHTS_2006_ORC: [Vora[eba165.extendtec.com.au:2202]] sap.hanavora.jdbc.VoraException: HL(9): Runtime error. (ORC Reader: Unsupported type char(2)
 (c++ exception))
[Vora[eba169.extendtec.com.au:2202]] sap.hanavora.jdbc.VoraException: HL(9): Runtime error. (ORC Reader: Unsupported type char(2)
 (c++ exception))
[Vora[eba156.extendtec.com.au:2202]] sap.hanavora.jdbc.VoraException: HL(9): Runtime error. (ORC Reader: Unsupported type char(2)
 (c++ exception)) with error code 0, status TStatusCode_ERROR_STATUS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem in Vora 1.2 and earlier. It will be working in the next Vora version (Vora 1.3).

Comment: Thanks Frank! Btw is it too late to jump on 1.3 Beta Testing bandwagon?